# Batch scripting: for /f did not work - invalid syntax

Tags: batch-file, command-line, dos

I using MS-DOS 7.10. My bash script is to copy all files in current and subfolder to another folder (I dont want to use xcopy). I used

```
For /f %%Y In (DirPath) Do
```

MS-DOS says "Invalid Syntax". What wrong with this command? Is it unsupported by command.com?

Comment: are you running this from the command line ?  If so use `%Y ` (you have to double the `%` only if you're running a bat file). btw you will have problems with filename containing space with this method. What's wrong with xcopy ??

Comment: /f is use when you want to search in the file. to get all the filenames use /r.

Comment: `robocopy` is another option.  Do you want to copy directory structure too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show us a little more of your batch.

In all probability, you are following the `DO` with a block.

A statement-sequence, counting as a single statement may be `(parenthesised over many lines if you like)` **but** if used on an `IF` statement, the `IF` and `(` **must** be on the same physical line (similarly, in a `FOR..DO`, if a block is used, the `DO` and `(` **must** be on the same physical line).

If however you are using real, genuine **MSDOS** rather than **CMD** (the windows emulator) then `for /f` is not supported under **MSDOS**

Comment: +1, The last sentence is the key. The OP is quite specific about MS-DOS 7.10 and COMMAND.COM